# Can't paste into MacVim

Tags: clipboard, macvim

I copy text from outside of Vim. ⌘V in other apps pastes text without problem. In MacVim, it doesn't work.

In Insert Mode, nothing appears. In Normal Mode, I get `E353: Nothing in register +`. This happens when `set clipboard=unnamed` is on or off.

Oddly enough, this was working before. What's wrong?

Comment: Do you usually start *MacVim* through the GUI (e.g. the dock, *Finder*, Spotlight, some launcher application), or via the command line? If you usually use the command line (e.g. `mvim`), do you regain clipboard access if you quit (not just close all the windows, but e.g. Command-Q) then restart “via the GUI”? Is there anything special about the environment from which you launch *MacVim*? E.g. `mvim` from inside a *tmux* pane that has not used something like my [`reattach-to-user-namespace` program](https://github.com/ChrisJohnsen/tmux-MacOSX-pasteboard).

Comment: @ChrisJohnsen That's probably the issue. I'll take a look soon. Thanks!

Comment: @ChrisJohnsen Thanks! `reattach-to-user-namespace` is excellent. You've saved a lot of nerds like me.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If you are using *tmux* and sometimes you initially launch *MacVim* via the `mvim` command-line program, then you might be encountering the problem that prompted me to write the [`reattach-to-user-namespace` command](https://github.com/ChrisJohnsen/tmux-MacOSX-pasteboard).

My guess is that clipboard access worked on prior occasions because you happened to have launched *MacVim* via a “normal” GUI method (e.g. the dock, *Finder*, Spotlight, etc.). The clipboard later became inaccessible after you had quit the prior instance of *MacVim* and relaunched it through (e.g.) `mvim` from inside a *tmux* session.

The core problem is that programs launched in certain contexts (i.e. inside a *tmux* session) end up with an environment that denies them access to certain services (e.g. the OS X pasteboard).

The *initial* launch is the important one here. New windows started by `mvim`-in-*tmux* (even without the above-linked wrapper program) should have access to the clipboard as long as *MacVim* was previously started “via the GUI” (maybe there are still some *MacVim* windows open, or maybe you have *MacVim* configured to keep running even when there are no windows open). Correspondingly, to regain access to the clipboard you will need to close all your existing *MacVim* windows, quit the application, then restart it in a way that has access to the clipboard (e.g. via the GUI, or “inside” the wrapper).

Once you have the above-linked wrapper program installed (it is also available through MacPorts and Homebrew), you can use a command like `reattach-to-user-namespace mvim` to ensure that **if** it ends up starting a new *MacVim* instance, then that new instance will have access to the clipboard. You might use an alias, shell function, or a script to make sure you always “wrap” `mvim`.

Several other commands also benefit from “wrapping” (`pbpaste`, `pbcopy`, `nohup`, `launchctl` (depending on which subcommand you are using)), so you may want to “wrap” your whole shell instead of the individual commands. The bit of the process environment that the “wrapper” modifies is inherited by child processes, so “wrapping” your shell will affect most commands you run from it. If you are using *tmux*, you could configure your `default-command` to automatically “wrap” your default *tmux* shells:

```
set-option -g default-command "reattach-to-user-namespace -l zsh"
```

Comment: How would I go about wrapping the whole shell?

Comment: If you already have a shell started, you can manually start a new, “wrapped” shell like this: `exec reattach-to-user-namespace zsh` (you can do it without the `exec` (e.g. for debugging purposes), but you will end up with an extra layer of shell). To have it done automatically, you will need to reconfigure whatever is starting your shell (e.g. *tmux*) to use the wrapper instead (e.g. via `default-command`); i.e. basically, just add `reattach-to-user-namespace` as a prefix.