# Vim compiled with +clipboard, but both + and * registers are unable to store yanks

Tags: macos, vim, clipboard

I am using Vim 7.4 homebrew version on Mavericks, with `+clipboard`. Under both vim and MacVim, yanking into either `+` or `*` has no effect and pasting from either one produces an error `E353: Nothing in register *` (or `+`).

Steps to produce it:

1. `$ vim -u None`
2. Insert some text
3. `"*yy`
4. `"*p` => `E353: Nothing in register *`
5. `:echo has("clipboard")` => `1`

This also means that both `set clipboard=unnamed` and `set clipboard=unnamedplus` cannot properly copy & paste. Can anyone suggest how I can troubleshoot this problem?

Thanks!

Related questions:

- [How to make vim paste from (and copy to) system's clipboard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11489428/how-to-make-vim-paste-from-and-copy-to-systems-clipboard)
  The accepted answer suggests:

  > try using "*yy or "+yy to copy a line to your system's clipboard. One or the other should work.

  But both registers have no effect.
- https://superuser.com/questions/680609/is-macvim-copy-to-clipboard-supposed-to-be-working-on-os-x-mavericks

Comment: are you SSH'd to the machine running vim ?

Comment: @user1281385 No, I tried using vim directly, tmux+vim, and MacVim.

Comment: @user1281385 I'm not sure if there's a good gvim port for Mac.

Comment: I suspect this may be a recent regression in vim for Mac OS X? Because the brewed custom MacVim uses the same version with the same patches.

Comment: Do you use tmux? tmux seems to have broken pasteboard and MacVim started from inside tmux cannot access the pasteboard. Refer to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16618992/cant-paste-into-macvim, https://hynek.me/articles/macvim-and-the-clipboard/

Comment: You should make that into an answer, Lie Ryan.

Comment: @LieRyan You are right. The solution to this is to install `reattach-to-user-namespace` from homebrew and start MacVim with `$ reattach-to-user-namespace mvim`. Thank you!

Comment: By default my tmux config tries to launch `zsh` with `reattach-to-user-namespace zsh -l`, but on my new system `reattach-to-user-namespace` is not yet installed and caused my confusion.

Answer (score 0):

As I said in answer to the related question you cite:

1) Install parcellite (a clipboard manager with a low memory footprint).

2) In your .vimrc file, add the following:

```
command Clip r !parcellite -c
```

3) Restart vim.

Now when you type in :Clip as an ex command, the contents of the clipboard will be pasted in at the cursor. You can then map the new command to a function key so as to be able to do this with one keystroke.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it works for Mac, but for my Debian machine it worked pretty well:
https://superuser.com/a/482597

Just installing the package `vim-gtk` turned vim able to handle the clipboard.

Answer (score 0):

Do you use tmux? tmux seems to have broken pasteboard and MacVim started from inside tmux cannot access the pasteboard. Refer to: [stackoverflow.com/questions/16618992/cant-paste-into-macvim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16618992/cant-paste-into-macvim), [hynek.me/articles/macvim-and-the-clipboard](https://hynek.me/articles/macvim-and-the-clipboard/) – Lie Ryan

You are right. The solution to this is to install `reattach-to-user-namespace` from homebrew and start MacVim with `$ reattach-to-user-namespace mvim`. Thank you! – koo

By default my tmux config tries to launch `zsh` with `reattach-to-user-namespace zsh -l`, but on my new system `reattach-to-user-namespace` is not yet installed and caused my confusion. – koo